# create XML file with variables for drop down box

Tags: xml, xslt

I created an XML file and can successfully use that information to create a drop down list. What I would like to achieve is to add variables from a stringResource file to create the values for the drop down list.

my original XML file is:

```
<root>
<row>
  <var name="--Select--"/>
</row>
<row>
  <var name="Agriculture"/>
</row>
<row>
  <var name="Airline"/>
</row>
<root>
```

in trying to add variables I have tried the following:

```
<PackageTransform>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:aspdnsf="urn:aspdnsf" exclude-result-prefixes="aspdnsf">
    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="row">

    <xsl:param name="pReplacement" select="'Something Different'"/>
        
        <root>
            <row>
                <xsl:value-of select="aspdnsf:StringResource('industry.cs.1')"/>
            </row>
            <row>
                Air
            </row>
            <row>
                <xsl:value-of select="$pReplacement" />
            </row>
        </root>
        
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

my working code, with the original XML file is:

```
            XmlNodeList industrylist = XmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("row");
        foreach (XmlNode Node in industrylist)
        {
            string industry = Node["var"].Attributes["name"].Value;
            _cboIndustryType.Items.Add(new ListItem(industry));
        }
```

With the top XML file my drop down list correctly lists all the names:

1. --Select--
2. Agriculture
3. Airline

I could not set the attribute name as a variable so I changed the code to look for the node innerXML like so:

```
                XmlNodeList industrylist = XmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("row");
        foreach (XmlNode Node in industrylist)
        {
            string industry = Node.InnerXml;
            _cboIndustryType.Items.Add(new ListItem(industry));
        }
```

but after many attempts such as the second XML file I am not able to get the variable to display correctly. I am seeing the following list:

1. <xsl:value-of select="aspdnsf:StringResource('industry.cs.1')" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"/>
2. Air
3. <xsl:value-of select="$pReplacement" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"/>

I would sure appreciate it if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably you are trying too much in one step. Separate the usage of the XML file for a drop down box from generating the XML via XSLT. In which area is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do what I want.

I just wrote 2 different XML files, one in each language then changed the code to pick the appropriate one based on locale.

```
            if (Customer.Current.LocaleSetting.Contains("es"))
            XmlDoc.Load(CommonLogic.SafeMapPath("~/XmlPackages") + "\\industry.drop.down.list.es-MX.xml.config");
        else
            XmlDoc.Load(CommonLogic.SafeMapPath("~/XmlPackages") + "\\industry.drop.down.list.xml.config");

        XmlNodeList industrylist = XmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("row");
        foreach (XmlNode Node in industrylist)
        {
            string industry = Node.InnerXml;
            _cboIndustryType.Items.Add(new ListItem(industry));
        }
```

Thanks!